# Integrating S3 upload/browsing with django-tinymce

Tags: django, amazon-s3, tinymce

I've been searching for resources on how to integrate Amazon S3 with TinyMCE. The best link I've come up with so far is: http://forums.aurigma.com/yaf_postst4033_Amazon-S3-File-Manager-for-TinyMCE-and-CKEditor.aspx

Does anyone have any experience integrating this into a Django app? If not, what are some alternative solutions for rich text editing and pulling in images from S3?

Comment: So, after speaking with the maintainer of django-filebrowser without Grappelli, it appears there is not a StorageBackend for Filebrowser for S3. Oh well, Django-CMS already provides file uploads that can push to S3 through django-storages, but it does complicate editing somewhat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [django-storages](http://code.welldev.org/django-storages/). Works perfectly.

Comment: How did you get everything working? Did you end up creating your own GUI frontend for it?

Comment: Actually, it's all transparent. When I upload an image through Django-CMS, they provide the form for the "Image" content plugin. From there it goes straight to the bucket specified by MEDIA_URL.

Comment: I've noticed that the file plugin doesn't work with the s3 backend.

Comment: I haven't tried the file plugin, but picture is working for me.

Comment: Disappointing this is the accepted answer. As others mentioned this user didn't test it or it broke at some point in the future and is no longer relevant. Seems the current django-tinymce package has a bad URL generator as the JS URL it creates via S3 is broken from my testing.

Comment: @Sensei I answered this question 9 years ago, and as I stated it worked for images. The fact that you expect a 9 year old answer to still be relevant, given how fast software development advances, is pretty ridiculous.

Answer (score 9):

If someone has searched this recently as I have and needs a solution to get django-tinymce4-lite working with django-storages and django-filebrowser-no-grappelli, I've managed to get it working by doing the following:

1) Follow this excellent tutorial: https://karansthr.gitlab.io/fosstack/how-to-set-up-tinymce-in-django-app/

2) When it comes to getting the s3 part working you'll need to install django-storages and set up you mediastorages as described in the instructions [here](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html)

3) You'll need to create a subclass of S3Boto3Storage and make that your `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` as below:

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'path.to.module.MediaStorage'
```

4) And inside that module create the MediaStorage class with the following API to work with FileBrowser

```
class MediaStorage(S3Boto3Storage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
    isfilecached = {}

    def isdir(self, name):
        if not name:  # Empty name is a directory
            return True

        if self.isfile(name):
            return False

        return True

    def isfile(self, name):
        if len(name.split('.')) > 1:
            return True
        try:
            name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
            if self.isfilecached.get(name) is not None:
                return self.isfilecached.get(name)

            f = S3Boto3StorageFile(name, 'rb', self)
            if "directory" in f.obj.content_type:
                isfile = False
            else:
                isfile = True
        except Exception:
            isfile = False
        self.isfilecached[name] = isfile
        return isfile

    def move(self, old_file_name, new_file_name, allow_overwrite=False):

        if self.exists(new_file_name):
            if allow_overwrite:
                self.delete(new_file_name)
            else:
                raise "The destination file '%s' exists and allow_overwrite is False" % new_file_name

        old_key_name = self._encode_name(self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(old_file_name)))
        new_key_name = self._encode_name(self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(new_file_name)))

        k = self.bucket.meta.client.copy(
            {
                'Bucket': self.bucket.name,
                'Key': new_key_name
            },
            self.bucket.name,
            old_key_name
        )

        if not k:
            raise "Couldn't copy '%s' to '%s'" % (old_file_name, new_file_name)

        self.delete(old_file_name)

    def makedirs(self, name):
        name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
        return self.bucket.meta.client.put_object(Bucket=self.bucket.name, Key=f'{name}/')

    def rmtree(self, name):
        name = self._normalize_name(self._clean_name(name))
        delete_objects = [{'Key': f"{name}/"}]

        dirlist = self.listdir(self._encode_name(name))
        for item in dirlist:
            for obj in item:
                obj_name = f"{name}/{obj}"
                if self.isdir(obj_name):
                    obj_name = f"{obj_name}/"
                delete_objects.append({'Key': obj_name})
        self.bucket.delete_objects(Delete={'Objects': delete_objects})

    def path(self, name):
        return name

    def listdir(self, name):
        directories, files = super().listdir(name)
        if '.' in files:
            files.remove('.')
        return directories, files

    def exists(self, name):
        if self.isdir(name):
            return True
        else:
            return super().exists(name)

    def get_modified_time(self, name):
        try:
            # S3 boto3 library requires that directorys have the trailing slash
            if self.isdir(name):
                name = f'{name}/'
            modified_date = super().get_modified_time(name)
        except Exception:
            modified_date = timezone.now()
        return modified_date

    def size(self, name):
        try:
            # S3 boto3 library requires that directorys have the trailing slash
            if self.isdir(name):
                name = f'{name}/'
            size = super().size(name)
        except Exception:
            size = 0
        return size
```

5) Make sure to put these in your Django Settings:

```
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'path.to.module.MediaStorage'

FILEBROWSER_DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS = None
FILEBROWSER_LIST_PER_PAGE = 5  # Speeds up the load of the filebrowser files

AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True     # Speeds up the load of the filebrowser files
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False    # Speeds up the load of the filebrowser files
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This saved my day!

Comment: @toose121 funny thing I was working on this today and did some enhancements to speed it up a bit, when the S3 folder has a lot of files it could take a while, this new class with the Django settings helped speed things up significantly

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go! Out of curiosity, do you have any idea how I would go about amending the above to support ONLY private media files, i.e. files that are not accessible via their s3 url, but only to authenticated users of my application?

I've used [this](https://testdriven.io/blog/storing-django-static-and-media-files-on-amazon-s3/) as a guide, but it appears that the link expires. How would you go about getting around that?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself but now I'm interested to try, would [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4) link help?  Perhaps limiting access to the bucket by the domain referred might be an option

Comment: This is actually what I went with. Nice to see validation in that you've also posted the same solution. The only thing I'm weary about is that my bucket shows a red asterisk that its public. That said the policy works well with my referrer-policy set to 'origin'. Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I get the same unnerving feeling seeing that big scary icon!  Thanks for the confirmation that it works.

Comment: This works perfectly as of December 2020. Don't forget the imports for the MediaStorage class: from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from storages.backends.s3boto3 import S3Boto3Storage

Comment: I've just got this working with django-filebrowser, but the page takes forever to load. I have 5 files listed per page and AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA / AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH set however it seems like it indexes the entire bucket / folder before returning the 5 results. Is there a way of speeding it up?