# what settings do i need to make django-filebrowser work with s3 storages?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-storage, django-filebrowser

I feel like I've tried just about everything here in getting static and user uploads folders to work with s3.  At this point when I run `collectstatic` all the folders inside `media` end up inside `static`, even though I'm pretty sure I configured things for two folders to be created.

I suspect it's something to do with django-filebrowser.  It seems that they have made some settings for storages but for the life of me I can't figure out how to make them work:

http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=storages

http://django-filebrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/admin.html?highlight=storages

Has anybody here gotten django-filebrowser to actually work with s3?  If not where else do you recommend I host user upload files?

django-filebrowser it tied pretty close to my app.  I have it setup to automatically create an array of thumbnails with each image upload and it works great.  Its useless to me if I can't get it off my local machine though.

excerpts from my `settings.py`:

```
from django.conf import settings
import dj_database_url  # HEROKU
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'filebrowser',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'frontpage',
    # adding south to try out with django 1.6
    'south',
    'inplaceeditform',
    'inplaceeditform_extra_fields',
    'storages',
    'boto',
)

# GRAPPELLI SPECIFIC RECOMMENDED ##
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)
#-------------------------------------------------------------
# DJANGO STORAGES 

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'addition_interiors_project.s3utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'addition_interiors_project.s3utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'xxxxxxxxxx'
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
)

MEDIA_ROOT = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/static/'
S3_URL = 'http://s3.amazonaws.com/%s' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + STATIC_ROOT
MEDIA_URL = S3_URL + MEDIA_ROOT

#-------------------------------------------------------------

#-------------------------------------------------------------
# DJANGO-FILEBROWSER
#-------------------------------------------------------------

FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS_BASEDIR = '_versions'
FILEBROWSER_VERSIONS = {
    'admin_thumbnail': {'verbose_name': 'Admin Thumbnail', 'width': 60, 'height': 60, 'opts': 'crop'},
    'thumbnail': {'verbose_name': 'Thumbnail (1 col)', 'width': 60, 'height': 60, 'opts': 'crop'},
    'small': {'verbose_name': 'Small (2 col)', 'width': 140, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
    'medium': {'verbose_name': 'Medium (4col )', 'width': 300, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
    'big': {'verbose_name': 'Big (6 col)', 'width': 460, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
    'large': {'verbose_name': 'Large (8 col)', 'width': 680, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
    'mega': {'verbose_name': 'Mega (12 col)', 'width': 940, 'height': '', 'opts': ''},
}

FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_VERSIONS = getattr(
    settings, 'FILEBROWSER_ADMIN_VERSIONS', ['thumbnail', 'small', 'medium', 'big', 'large', 'mega'])
```

also my s3utils.py:

```
from storages.backends.s3boto import S3BotoStorage

StaticRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='static')
MediaRootS3BotoStorage = lambda: S3BotoStorage(location='media')
```

my folder structure:

**addition_interiors_project**

..manage.py

**..addition_interiors_project**

**....addition_interiors_project**

**....media**

**....static**

**....frontpage**

....s3utils.py

....settings.py

....urls.py

....wsgi.py

Comment: Have you managed to get an answer for this question?

Comment: No I moved on to Django Filer

Comment: In case anyone is still interested in doing this I managed to solve this and posted my findings here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55535191/1184181

Answer (score 0):

You can use filebrowser_s3 configuration is almost the same.

https://pypi.org/project/filebrowser-s3/

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...,
'filebrowser_s3',
]
```