# What is the recommended place to deploy django-filebrowser, it looks like S3 is not the place

Tags: django, amazon-s3, django-filebrowser

I have been unsuccessful in deploying django-filebrowser using Amazon S3.  It appears that many others are having difficulty as well.  So far none of the github tickets have helped me.

Is there another more typical method of deploying user uploads with django-filebrowser?

Comment: Do you also have django-storages and python-dateutil installed?

Comment: Yes I do, I saw that on some Google groups discussion I think. I also posted a very detailed question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22775435/what-settings-do-i-need-to-make-django-filebrowser-work-with-s3-storages&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjAB&usg=AFQjCNE6t1vBp-aD-ZhzCBefcUowHsKIFQ&sig2=4r-EOLmW6UGVFu0VvtN7nQ